# How do I prove this map is a two-sided inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

[image]

I almost solved it, to prove the bijectivity, we have to show that $\theta^{-1}=f^{-1}$.

Since $f$ is an epimorphism, we have $\theta(\theta^{-1}(G))=\theta(f^{-1}(G))=f(f^{-1}(G))=G$, for any $G\in S_{M'}$.

My problem is to prove that $\theta^{-1}$ is a left inverse of $\theta$, I need help in this part.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $\theta^{-1}(\theta(G)) = f^{-1}(f(G))$ by the definition of $\theta$ and $\theta^{-1}$.

Now, $f$ is a homomorphism, and for every homomorphism and any set $T \subset M$, one has

$$f^{-1}(f(T)) = \{m \in M \colon \bigl(\exists t \in T\bigr)(f(t) = f(m))\} = \{m \in M \colon \bigl(\exists t \in T\bigr)(m-t \in \ker f)\} = T + \ker f$$

By assumption, $G$ is a submodule with $\ker f \subset G$, so $G + \ker f = G$.